# How to pick the non-NULL value from a set of columns?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have table with 1 + 5 columns as follows.

MemberID ==> represents Member_ID

Value1 ==> Represents Value1

Value2 ==>  Represents Value2

Value3 ==>  Represents Value3

Value4 ==>  Represents Value4

Value5 ==>  Represents Value5

Only one column is not null at any given time(In the set of Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4 and Value5).

I want to run a query where in I get the result as Member_ID, Value where the value is non null value from any of the 5 Value columns.

How to do that in TSQL?
Thank you,
Smith

Answer (score 4):

```
select memberID, coalesce(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5)
from myTable
```

If the possibility exists that all of the values could be null, you may want to default to a value.

```
select memberID, coalesce(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, <default>)
from myTable
```

Comment: Getting picky, but no need for the extra function call.
coalesce(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, <default>)

Comment: @Bill Go figure, I didn't know that.  Modifying.

Comment: OOPS! All the Value1 to Value5 are of different datatype columns. They are Boolean, int, Datetime.

Comment: @LaysomeSmith In that case, you could try casting them to the same type in the coalesce.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a case statement

```
select memberID,
       case
           when Value1 is not null then
               Value1
           when Value2 is not null then
               Value2  
           when Value3 is not null then
               Value3
           when Value4 is not null then
               Value4
           when CValue5 is not null then
               Value5
       end as [Value]
from myTable
```

There is also the possibility to add an "else" to the case statement to return a default if all values were null.

Comment: Also, in the case statements you can cast to a common return type if the datatypes of Values1 to 5 have different types.