# How to pick non-null from a list of columns in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

As part of a LINQ query I have a series of columns, only one of which will ever contain a value, how do I assign that single value to a variable without having to do something like

```
myVal = column1.hasValue ? column1.value : column2.hasValue ? column2.value : column3.hasValue ? column3.value : etc
```

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620738/how-to-pick-the-non-null-value-from-a-set-of-columns) but with LINQ instead of SQL.

Unfortunately, handling anything DB side with SQL isn't an option.

Comment: Can we see that query?

Comment: Is it possible that none of the columns contain a value? (== all are  null?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var values = new[]{ column1, column2, column3 };
var value = values.First(nullable => nullable.HasValue).Value;
```

or even more concise:

```
var value = (column1 ?? column2 ?? column3).Value;
```

Comment: For case when all values are null `values.Where(nullable => nullable.HashValue).FirstOrDefault().GetValueOrDefault()`

Comment: @Fabio: as it seems to be a rule that one has to be non-null i find it dangerous to select an arbitrary value then. I prefer the exception for the case that there is a bug :)

Comment: Correct, one does have to be non-null, and there is logic in place that (hopefully) enforces that correctly